# I want to use Clip to play wav file with Java , but none of the three java files was working

Tags: multithreading, animation, audio, graphics

The first file: No sound was generated.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class AudioTest {

    public AudioTest() {
    
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        System.out.println(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("C:\\audio1.wav"));//to see if the sound file is found
    
        try{
          Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
              AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("C:\\audio1.wav"));
              clip.open(inputStream);
              clip.start();
              while (!clip.isRunning())
                  Thread.sleep(10);
              while (clip.isRunning())
                  Thread.sleep(10);
              clip.close();
            } catch (Exception  e)
                {
                  System.out.println("something failed");
                }
        System.out.println("done"); //to see if the sound is finished playing
 } 
}
```

The second file: No sound was generated.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class AudioTest {

    public AudioTest() {
    
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        System.out.println(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("C:\\audio1.wav"));//to see if the sound file is found
    
        try{
          Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
              AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("C:\\audio1.wav"));
              clip.open(inputStream);
              clip.start();
              clip.close();
            } catch (Exception  e)
                {
                  System.out.println("something failed");
                }
     } 
}
```

The third file: No sound was generated.

```
import java.io.*;     
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Test13 {
    static String filename = "C:\\audio1.wav";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try
        {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filename)));
            clip.start();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
         
    }
}
```

The problem is no sound was generated when executing any one of the above three files. But now I have found a best way to solve this problem by using File SoundFile = new File("src//audio1.wav");

Answer (score 0):

I've had my best results when using URL for obtaining the audio resource.

```
Clip clip;

void makeAudio1Cue()
{
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("audio/" + filename);
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, ais.getFormat());
    Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    clip.open(ais);
}

void playAudio1Cue()
{
    clip.setFramePosition(0);
    clip.start();
}
```

In this case, the audio file is in a subdirectory, named "audio", of the file folder that is holding the "this" class.

It will be helpful if you post any error messages that you get.

Comment: URL is a pointer to a "resource" on the World Wide Web. My audio file is located on my won computer. I don't think I want to use URL.

Comment: If you aren't planning to run this code on anyone else's computer, using File is probably going to be fine. There used to be cases where File would fail due to Mark/Reset errors, but I haven't seen that come up in a long while. But if you wish to package the program in a jar file, or self-contained jvm (jlink-built) for distribution, a "relative" file location and a URL with the getResource method is the most common practice. A URL can see into a jar. A File cannot. URL is used for both local and www files. Regardless, you need a DataLine.Info step.

Comment: Great ideal! I will try that later.

Comment: Could you please add something like 'include', main function etc. to make it a complete and executable java class file? You know I am just a beginner.

Comment: If you use an IDE (highly recommended) it will help fill in the needed imports, if that is what you mean. Isn't "include" more of a JavaScript thing? If you need more guidance, can I suggest this plan: write a program that prints "hello world" on the console when you press a button. I'll help you add the small amount of additional code needed to initialize the sound, as well as the small amount needed to play the sound file when the button is pressed, if you don't figure it out yourself first. (I think you will.)

Comment: I am using eclipse as IDE. Yes, I can find imports from there when I code by myself, but when I copy your code into there, it showed up a lot of errors.  I am planning to write a two-threaded program, one thread for printing a moving music score(animated graphic, It is done.), the other thread for playing a wav music file which is the output of the music score. Yes, I will try to write a program that prints "hello world" on the console when I press a button.

Comment: Looking forward to seeing the "hello world" button code working, ready to help with audio playback once it is done. Coordinating a moving score with music is no mean feat though. I'm going to suggest using a SourceDataLine that reports back its timing progress, where you can use its frame count to coordinate the rate of the visual playback.

Comment: I added import java.awt.event.*; and bPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          System.out.println("Hello World");          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World");}}); into my code. Then executed it, now the "hello world" button code was working.

Comment: Great! Please post the new code in your original post. I will then edit my answer to address the code you post.

Comment: Here I can only post the relevant portion for printing out "Hello world" in the next comment because when I tried to post my whole code I got only a mess.

Comment: btPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       System.out.println("Hello World");                         
     } });

Comment: I tried to add my whole current code into my original post but what I got was just a mess. So here I can only post the portion that you want me to print

Comment: btPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
  });

Comment: My email is dienfoonwu@gmail.com. I appreciate your email!

Comment: I have sent you an email. If you don't get an email, please let me know! I just installed a new email server (my first time configuring such a thing!) and there might be some bugs to work out. If it doesn't work, I will write again from a different email address.

Comment: I already received your email and sent you my two files, Test7.java and .wav file. Hope you can receive them successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The first java file seems working now

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

 class AudioTest {

    public void AudioPlay() {

        ClassLoader classLoader = 
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

        try{
          Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
          AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("audio1.wav"));

          clip.open(inputStream);
          clip.start();
          while (!clip.isRunning())
              Thread.sleep(10);
          while (clip.isRunning())
              Thread.sleep(10);
          clip.close();
        } catch (Exception e)
            {
              e.printStackTrace(); 
              System.out.println(e); 
            }
        System.out.println("done"); //to see if the sound is finished playing
    } 
}
public class Test11 {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException
    {
    AudioTest au1 = new AudioTest();
    au1.AudioPlay();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code is the best way to play .wav files:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;
   
// To play sound using Clip, the process need to be alive.
// Hence, we use a Swing application.
public class T55 extends JFrame {

// Constructor
   public T55() {
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setTitle("Test Sound Clip");
      this.setSize(300, 200);
      this.setVisible(true);
   
      try {
         // Open an audio input stream.
          File soundFile = new File("src//audio1.wav");
          AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
          
         // Get a sound clip resource.
         Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
         // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
         clip.open(audioIn);
         clip.start();
      } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new T55();
   }
}
```